# Using xbindkeys to assign suspend to Pause/Break key

Tags: ubuntu-mate, xbindkeys

Xbindkeys sure has a person doing some "fancy dancing" trying to get a command assigned to a key.

Using material from here,

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xbindkeys#GUI_method

This is in .xbindkeysrc.

```
systemctl suspend
m:0x0 + c:127
```

I got to this step and got stumped ???

```
Making changes permanent

Once you are done configuring your keys, edit your xprofile or xinitrc file (depending on your window manager) and place xbindkeys

before the line that starts your window manager or DE.
```

This shows my window manager.

```
wmctrl -m
Name: Metacity (Marco)
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

I can not find xprofile or xinitrc ??

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211307/persistent-remapping-of-keys-with-setxkbmap-or-xorg-configuration

Comment: Thanks, I used Keyboard Shortcuts and assigned the suspend command to Alt S. @pierrely